# Identifying an individual USB device in Python

Tags: python

I'm working with some Python where I have 5 USB devices plugged into the computer and I'm interacting with them. I've been programming for a number of years in PHP, but I'm pretty new to the application side.

I am currently looking for a way to uniquely identify a device such as a device serial number, one that isn't assigned by the computer, but from the device itself. Does something like that exist? If it does, is there a simple way to access it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110310/simple-way-to-query-connected-usb-devices-info-in-python

Comment: The answer appears to be that there is no way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053764/how-to-identify-uniquely-a-usb-device

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what platform you're using, but a cross-platform solution to dealing with serial ports is PySerial:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Comment: Serial numbers aren't related to serial ports.